# Angular-ui modal with no animation flickers

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, flicker

Been using `angular-ui` for a while now but I can't get rid of the black flickering when using it without animation. Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5xVFUqfY2BUX1MPO7YS?p=preview).

```
 $scope.opend = function() {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: false,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: 'sm',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

Click a few times and notice that the backgrounds flickers black when the dialog opens / closes. Turns out that on tablets it gets quite much worse.

Even their example on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ is flickering.

Any ideas of how I can avoid this black flickering or am I forced to change the modal im using?

Comment: you could try to use $timeout, but I believe angular-ui already uses $timeout. I use the bootstrap modal's, but calling in a $timeout function, without angular-ui, and it no flicks.

Comment: This is a bug discussed heavily here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8768

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when closing the dialog.

Hiding the dialog right before closing helps a bit:

```
$('.modal-dialog').hide();
// then call modalInstance.close()
```

In order to fix all dialogs in the project I created a 'decorator' in the config function:

```
angular.module( ... ).config( [..., '$provide', function(..., $provide){
        $provide.decorator('$modal', [
            '$delegate', function($delegate) {
                return {
                    open: function (modalOptions) {
                        var modifiedResult = $delegate.open(modalOptions);

                        var originalClose = modifiedResult.close;

                        modifiedResult.close = function (result) {
                            angular.element('.modal-dialog').hide();
                            originalClose(result);
                        }

                        return modifiedResult;
                    },
                    getPromiseChain: function() {
                        return $delegate.getPromiseChain();
                    }
                };
            }
        ]);
}] );
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Use `animation: true` which avoid flickering